# Sending different values of input with different buttons in php form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form in my code

```
<form class="validate form-horizontal" role="form" id="formLogin" action='actions.php' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo @$selectedUser['id'];?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="j" value="<?php echo "3"; ?>" />

    <div class="form-group clearfix">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-9">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Save&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
            <a class="btn btn-default" href="index.php">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group clearfix">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-9">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Approve&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
            <input style="margin-left: 10px;" type="checkbox" name="emailCheckBox" style="height: 25px">
            <label style="margin-left: 10px;" class="control-label">Email Tami</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have two different buttons here , `Save and Approve`. 
There are atleast 7 more input fields in this form. Now i want it, so that when save button is clicked, it should send value of `j = 3` and if Approve is pressed, it should send value of j to be 4

How can I override the form activity and maybe write some code in javascript to achive this, keeping in mind the data of other 7 etc input fields is being sent too, and its same for both buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add necessary attributes for that purpose:

```
<button type="submit" name="action" value="save" class="btn btn-success">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Save&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
<button type="submit" name="action" value="approve" class="btn btn-success">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Approve&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
```

In this example, add the `name="action"` and their respective values for each button:

```
value="save"
value="approve"
```

Then in PHP:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $action = $_POST['action']; // the value here will be either "save" or "approve"
    // so now your next course will depend on this value
    $j = null;
    if($action == 'save') {
        $j = 3;
    } elseif ($action == 'approve') {
        $j = 4;
    }
}
```

Or if you do not want to go this route, then you can just manipulate it client-side:

```
$('button[name="action"]').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var action = $(this).attr('value');
    if(action == 'save') {
        $('input[name="j"]').attr('value', 3);
    } else if(action == 'approve') {
        $('input[name="j"]').attr('value', 4);
    }
    $('#formLogin').submit();
});
```

Then in PHP, just normally access `$_POST['j'];`

Answer (score 1):

Set the name for the form

```
<form class="validate form-horizontal" role="form" name="form" id="formLogin" action='actions.php' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

.

A pure vanilla javascript would be

```
var button = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-success');
var input = document.forms['form'].j;

document.forms['form'].addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}) 

button[1].addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
    input = parseInt(input.value) +1;
    console.log(input);
    document.forms['form'].submit();
})

button[0].addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
    document.forms['form'].submit();
})
```

.

#### JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/2aa52wak/2/.